# Obtain Account URL using the REST API

Tags: soql, rest-api

I would like to obtain the Account URL: [https://[company_name].lightning.force.com/lightning/r/Account/[AccoundId]/view](https://%5Bcompany_name%5D.lightning.force.com/lightning/r/Account/%5BAccoundId%5D/view)
through the API so that I can refer to this page in my own application.

However, I can't find this URL anywhere in the data and SOQL doesn't allow for concatenation functions in the queries.

Does anyone know how to obtain this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are allowed to create a new field on the Account object, you could create a new formula field to return the record URL, and then query that field, try something like this:

```
LEFT($Api.Partner_Server_URL_550, FIND('/services/', $Api.Partner_Server_URL_550)) + 'lightning/r/Account/' + Id + '/view'
```

hope this helps!